# What we mean when we say "much up the creek"

Tags: meaning

What  we mean when we say "much up the creek"

Comment: Do you know what the idiom "up the creek without a paddle" means? It means an extreme example of this.

Comment: [Please review question formation: *What do we mean when we say x.*] This question will be deleted or migrated. Please read the Help section, top right of your screen,

Comment: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/up-the-creek